# Check to see if file date created and modified were modified?

Tags: windows-7, windows, linux, macos, ubuntu

Is there a way to tell if a file's date created/modified dates were adjusted artificially via command line. I am talking about for files like Word and Excel documents, so if someone opened and modified a word file on 12/1, but then it was changed to 11/1, is there anyway to see this?

Also does the possibility of this matter what OS the file was created on? I need to know how to do this for OSX, ubuntu, and 7.

Thanks.

Comment: And what does that mean? Edit: I see, I am not sure if I am supposed to answer that or you are just interjecting with a witty comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you've enabled auditing, no, you won't be able to see if it's been modified.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you can trust the clock of the system the files are stored on, no, and maybe not even then. I could set the clock back (or forward) in the BIOS, modify the file, restart the system and correct the clock in the BIOS.

Comment: @pnuts rephrased